# Get component by key from list rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

With vue I render a list of custom components. How can I access a particular rendered component by its key name?

```
<component v-for="field in r.fields"
                       :key="field.name"
                       :field="field"
                       :is="field.component"
            ></component>
```

The custom component has some methods I need to access from another custom component.

Comment: Components in `v-for` cycle are independent so they don't have access to each other. Could you please detail what exactly do you mean by getting access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `ref` you can search for the component by matching against the key:

```vue
<component v-for="field in r.fields"
  :key="field.name"
  :field="field"
  :is="field.component"
  ref="comps"
></component>
```

```js
this.$refs.comps.find(comp => comp.$vnode.key === 'foo')
```

Comment: I did what you wrote. But 'this.$refs.comps' returns undefined.

Comment: But in this.$refs I see the comps: https://monosnap.com/file/uOVtClGKqJsCySimRkFYvoyKE0AE3v

Comment: Yes, you need to wait for Vue to re-render. Try using `this.$nextTick` or `setTimeout` before accessing it.